# Nesting ifelse in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to nest `ifelse` in R to create a new vector C, where if both vectors A and B are missing, then NA; otherwise, if either vector contains 1, then "Yes"; otherwise, "No". 
Example:

```
A  B  C
1  1  Yes
1  0  Yes
0  1  Yes
0  0  No
NA 1  Yes
0  NA No
NA NA NA
```

The below is what I've been playing around with in various iterations, but I can't get it to work correctly. Any suggestions?

```
df <- df %>% mutate(C=ifelse((is.na(A) & is.na(B)), NULL, ifelse((A==1 | B==1), "Yes", "No")))
```

(Perhaps there's a better way which doesn't use `ifelse` at all, which I'd also be open to, but for my own understanding it would be nice to know how to get this way to work as well!)

Many thanks!

Comment: You should have `NA` instead of `NULL` in the first `ifelse()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative to `ifelse()`:

```
df$C <- c("No", "Yes")[(rowMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE) > 0) + 1]

df
   A  B    C
1  1  1  Yes
2  1  0  Yes
3  0  1  Yes
4  0  0   No
5 NA  1  Yes
6  0 NA   No
7 NA NA <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option via nested `ifelse`:

```
df$C <- ifelse(rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE) > 0,
    "Yes",
    ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df)) < 2,
        "No",
        "NA"
    )
)
```

which gives

```
> df
   A  B   C
1  1  1 Yes
2  1  0 Yes
3  0  1 Yes
4  0  0  No
5 NA  1 Yes
6  0 NA  No
7 NA NA  NA
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, NA), B = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `case_when` function from `dplyr` package.

```
# This was not tested, but should give your a flavour of how it might work
df <- df %>% mutate(
  C = dplyr::case_when(
    is.na(A) & is.na(B) ~ NA,
    A == 1 | B == 1 ~ "Yes",
    TRUE ~ "No"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you could do somehting like :

```
df$C <- ifelse(is.na(df$A)*is.na(df$B),NA,ifelse(ifelse(is.na(df$A),FALSE,df$A==1) + ifelse(is.na(df$B),FALSE,df$B==1)>0,"Yes","No"))
```

?